# Optimal method of comparing a vector of numbers to values in another vector

Tags: r, vector

Suppose I have two vectors of values:

```
a <- c(1,3,4,5,6,7,3)
b <- c(3,5,1,3,2)
```

And I want to apply some function, `FUN`, to each of the inputs of `a` against the whole of `b`, what's the most efficient way to do it.

More specifically, in this case for each of the elements in `a` I want to know for each value of 'a', how many of the elements in `b` are greater than or equal to that value. The naïve approach is to do the following:

```
sum(a < b)
```

Of course, this doesn't work as it attempts to iterate over each of the vectors in parallel and gives me the warning:

> longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

The output, btw, of that command is `3`.

However, in my situation, what I'd like to see is an output that is:

```
0 2 4 4 5 5 2
```

Of course, I realize I can do it using a for loop as such:

```
out <- c()
for (i in a) {
    for (i in a) { out[length(out) + 1] = sum(b<i)}
}
```

Likewise, I could use `sapply` as such:

```
sapply(a, function(x)sum(b<x))
```

However, I'm trying to be a good R programmer and stay away from for loops and `sapply` seems to be very slow.  Are there other alternatives?

For what it's worth, I'm doing this a couple of million times where `length(b)` is always less than `length(a)` and `length(a)` ranges from 1 to 30.

Comment: Do both the vectors `a,b` vary in each of your million iterations, or is one of them fixed?

Comment: Both vectors are generated multiple different times while going through all of the data. So, yes, they do vary, each one has about 10000 different values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
findInterval(a - 0.5, sort(b))
```

---

Speed improvement from a) avoiding `sort`, and b) avoiding overhead in `findInterval` and `order` by using simpler `.Internal` wrappers:

```
order2 = function(x) .Internal(order(T, F, x))

findInterval2 = function(x, vec, rightmost.closed=F, all.inside=F) {
  nx <- length(x)
  index <- integer(nx)
  .C('find_interv_vec', xt=as.double(vec), n=length(vec),
    x=as.double(x), nx=nx, as.logical(rightmost.closed),
    as.logical(all.inside), index, DUP = FALSE, NAOK=T,
    PACKAGE='base')
  index
}

> system.time(for (i in 1:10000) findInterval(a - 0.5, sort(b)))
   user  system elapsed 
   1.22    0.00    1.22 
> system.time(for (i in 1:10000) sapply(a, function(x)sum(b<x)))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.79    0.00    0.78 
> system.time(for (i in 1:10000) rowSums(outer(a, b, ">")))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.72    0.00    0.72 
> system.time(for (i in 1:10000) findInterval(a - 0.5, b[order(b)]))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.42    0.00    0.42 
> system.time(for (i in 1:10000) findInterval2(a - 0.5, b[order2(b)]))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.16    0.00    0.15
```

The complexity of defining `findInterval2` and `order2` is probably only warranted if you have heaps of iterations with fairly small N.

Also timings for larger N:

```
> a = rep(a, 100)
> b = rep(b, 100)
> system.time(for (i in 1:100) findInterval(a - 0.5, sort(b)))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.01    0.00    0.02 
> system.time(for (i in 1:100) sapply(a, function(x)sum(b<x)))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.67    0.00    0.68 
> system.time(for (i in 1:100) rowSums(outer(a, b, ">")))
   user  system elapsed 
   3.67    0.26    3.94 
> system.time(for (i in 1:100) findInterval(a - 0.5, b[order(b)]))
   user  system elapsed 
      0       0       0 
> system.time(for (i in 1:100) findInterval2(a - 0.5, b[order2(b)]))
   user  system elapsed 
      0       0       0
```

Comment: @Charles: this is slower than the `sapply` solution of the OP -- I tested it by doing `system.time( replicate( 10000, ... ) )`.

Comment: For small a/b, the sort dominates the run-time. `b[order(b)]` benchmarks about 4x faster than `sort(b)`, and twice as fast as the `sapply` original on my box. For larger a/b (rep(100)), you get orders of magnitude improvement by using findInterval.

Comment: Most of the remaining overhead is in stuff like the `is.sorted` and `is.na` checks in `findInterval`, and the various checks in order. If you define thinner wrappers around those functions (eg `order2 = function(x) .Internal(order(T, F, x))`), then it gets about another 3x faster.

Comment: Nicely done @Charles +1 - a nice solution using a function I haven't come across much. Can you post your findInterval2 and order2 functions to complete the answer?

Answer (score 5):

One option is to use `outer()` to apply the binary operator function `>` to `a` and `b`:

```
> outer(a, b, ">")
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
[1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
[3,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[4,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[5,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[6,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[7,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

The answer to the Q is then given by the row sums of the result above:

```
> rowSums(outer(a, b, ">"))
[1] 0 2 4 4 5 5 2
```

For this example data set, this solution is slightly faster that `findIntervals()` but not by much:

```
> system.time(replicate(1000, findInterval(a - 0.5, sort(b))))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.131   0.000   0.132 
> system.time(replicate(1000, rowSums(outer(a, b, ">"))))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.078   0.000   0.079
```

It is also slightly faster than the `sapply()` version, but marginally:

```
> system.time(replicate(1000, sapply(a, function(x)sum(b<x))))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.082   0.000   0.082
```

@Charles notes that most of the time in the `findInterval()` example is used by `sort()`, which can be circumvented via `order()`. When this is done, the `findInterval()` solution is faster than the `outer()` solution:

```
> system.time(replicate(1000, findInterval(a - 0.5, b[order(b)])))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.049   0.000   0.049
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd be very wary of using the internals of R in production code. The internals can easily change between releases.

sort.int is faster than sort - and it's just plain weird that b[order(b)] is faster than sort.int(b). R could definitely improve its sorting...

And unless you use the internals of R, it seems like using vapply is actually faster:

```
> system.time(for (i in 1:10000) findInterval(a - 0.5, sort(b)))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.99    0.00    0.98 
> system.time(for (i in 1:10000) findInterval(a - 0.5, sort.int(b)))
   user  system elapsed 
    0.8     0.0     0.8 
> system.time(for (i in 1:10000) findInterval(a - 0.5, b[order(b)]))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.32    0.00    0.32 
> system.time(for (i in 1:10000) sapply(a, function(x)sum(b<x)))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.61    0.00    0.59 
> system.time(for (i in 1:10000) vapply(a, function(x)sum(b<x), 0L))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.18    0.00    0.19
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a add-on note: if you know the range of the values for each vector, then it might be quicker to calculate the max and mins first, e.g.

```
order2 = function(x) .Internal(order(T, F, x))
findInterval2 = function(x, vec, rightmost.closed=F, all.inside=F) {
  nx <- length(x)
  index <- integer(nx)
  .C('find_interv_vec', xt=as.double(vec), n=length(vec),
    x=as.double(x), nx=nx, as.logical(rightmost.closed),
    as.logical(all.inside), index, DUP = FALSE, NAOK=T,
    PACKAGE='base')
  index
}

f <- function(a, b) {
  # set up vars
  a.length <- length(a)
  b.length <- length(b)
  b.sorted <- b[order2(b)]
  b.min <- b.sorted[1]
  b.max <- b.sorted[b.length]
  results <- integer(a.length)

  # pre-process minimums
  v.min <- which(a <= b.min)

  # pre-process maximums
  v.max <- which(a > b.max)
  results[v.max] <- b.max

  # compare the rest
  ind <- c(v.min, v.max)
  results[-ind] <- findInterval2(a[-ind] - 0.5, b.sorted)
  results
}
```

Which gives the following timeings

```
> N <- 10
> n <- 1e5
> b <- runif(n, 0, 100)
> a <- runif(n, 40, 60) # NB smaller range of values than b
> summary( replicate(N, system.time(findInterval2(a - 0.5, b[order2(b)]))[3]) )
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 0.0300  0.0300  0.0400  0.0390  0.0475  0.0500 
> summary( replicate(N, system.time(f(a, b))[3]) )
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  0.010   0.030   0.030   0.027   0.030   0.040
```

However, if you don't know the ranges ahead of time, or can't make an educated guess about them, then this would probably be slower.